# Is there a way to programmatically track changes in a word doc?

Tags: office-js

I am trying to subscribe to changes in a word document via the javascript add-in.

What I have tried is to find a way to use the ContentController track function. Was not able top find samples. The documentation of the function refers to context.trackedObjects.add yet was not able to trace a documentation for this function.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=office-js#track--

Alternatively would like to use the WordApiBeta onDataChanged event, but again can not find any documentation.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=office-js#ondatachanged

Comment: did you found any workaround to track changes in word add-in?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to [ContentControl.onDataChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=office-js#ondatachanged), there doesn't seem to be any more documentation than that article. But events are registered and handled in Word.js just as they are in Excel.js. So working some with [Excel events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events) should give you an idea of how to use `onDataChanged` in Word.

There is some information about tracked objects at [ClientRequestObject.trackedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.clientrequestcontext?view=office-js#trackedobjects) and at [TrackedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.trackedobjects?view=office-js) which shows a couple overrides of the `add()` method.

If you are going to be working with tracked objects, I recommend [Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins).

By the way, if you get your code working with either `ContentControl.onDataChanged` or `TrackedObjects.add`, we'd love to have a sample submitted to [office-js-snippets](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets) for use in [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862).